# Knockout Invalidstaterror

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
self.save_form = function (data, event) {

    if (event != undefined && event.srcElement != undefined && event.srcElement.classList != undefined && event.srcElement.classList.contains("save_form")) {
        var processData = false;
        var contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        var stringify = true;


        var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(autoDeployViewModel); //Invalid State Error
}
```

When unmapping the viewModel in the above live I am getting an InvalidStateError whenever my IntakeForm observable array is filled.

I have narrowed it down to whenever my IntakeForm object is populated:

```
AutoDeployFormViewModel = function () {
//Intake Form View Model
var self = this;

self.File = {};
self.XPathCollection = ko.observableArray([new XPathConfig()]);
self.IntakeForm = ko.observableArray([new IntakeFormData("Upload your web config.")]);
}
```

The IntakeForm object gets fully populated whenever these events are called:

```
 whereAttrSelected: function (data, event) {
        //alert("where selected");   
        if (event.srcElement.classList.contains("whereAttrSelected")) {
            data.XPathConfig._selectedWhereClauseAttribute("[@" + data.Attribute + "=" + '"' + data.Value + '"' + ']');
            data.XPathConfig._radioButtonWhere(event.srcElement); //store reference to rbtn that was clicked 
        }

        return true;
    },
    transformAttrSelected: function (data, event) {
        if (event.srcElement.classList.contains("transformAttrSelected")) {
            data.XPathConfig._radioButtonTransform(event.srcElement); //store reference to rbtn that was clicked 
            data.XPathConfig._selectedTransformAttribute(data.Attribute);
            var intakeFormData = autoDeployViewModel().IntakeForm();

            var xPath = attr._fullXPath + data.XPathConfig._selectedWhereClauseAttribute() + '/' + "@" + data.XPathConfig._selectedTransformAttribute(); // XPATH STRING MANIPULATION
            var updatedIntakeFormData = [];
            updatedIntakeFormData.push(new IntakeFormData(xPath, attr)); //push most recent addition

            //push the rest of the observable array 
            for (var i = 0; i < intakeFormData.length; i++) {
                updatedIntakeFormData.push(new IntakeFormData(intakeFormData[i].Intake, intakeFormData[i].Attribute))
            }

            autoDeployViewModel().update_intake_form(updatedIntakeFormData);//update ui by replacing XPaths

        }

        return true;

    }
```

Basically XPathConfig click events allow me to store some string data and a reference to the selected radio button into an observable. Problem is when I try to unmap this when I am ready to convert to a javascript object, the invalid state error occurs.

```
data.XPathConfig._selectedWhereClauseAttribute("[@" + data.Attribute + "=" + '"' + data.Value + '"' + ']');
data.XPathConfig._radioButtonWhere(event.srcElement); //store reference to rbtn that was clicked 

data.XPathConfig._radioButtonTransform(event.srcElement); //store reference to rbtn that was clicked 
                      data.XPathConfig._selectedTransformAttribute(data.Attribute);
```

Can someone explain why the state might be invalid during unmapping the viewModel if the above observables are set?